# QIODevice::readAll() not working properly?

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, arduino, qiodevice

I am currently working on a project that involves serial communication between a Arduino and a laptop. I know the Arduino is indeed sending the data that I need, see this picture: http://s1.postimg.org/w5wisaetr/Help.png

Now on the other end my laptop is connected to the Arduino and running a program that I made using QT Creator. However, when reading data from the serial Port I can't get the program to display this information.

I connected my readData() function to be executed when data is received like this:

```
connect(m_serialPort, SIGNAL(readyRead()), m_dataGathering, SLOT(newData()));
```

This works and the newData() function is called whenever something in transmitted from the Arduino. However the function newData() does not display the data that I need.

newData():

```
void DataGathering::newData()
{
    QByteArray rMsg = m_serial->readAll();
    qDebug() << rMsg.constData();
}
```

This only sends empty message to the display. Like this: http://s2.postimg.org/dkcyip2u1/empty.png

The following code however works:

```
void DataGathering::newData()
{
    QByteArray rMsg("\nTest...");// = m_serial->readAll();
    qDebug() << rMsg.constData();
}
```

This code display the message like it should.
However, another difference in the output display is that when the working code is executed my console also displays a lot of Framing errors, I assumed this is because the baudrate of the unwanted characters differs from the data that I need.

That is why i started questioning the readAll() function. 
It is also obvious that the Arduino is not only sending the data that I need but also some unwanted characters (see image in first link), but I don't see this as a problem since I will filter this out later.

All help is very much appreciated.

**Update:** I found out that the readAll() function is returning QByteArrays with size() equals to 0.

Comment: the link with a image of the display from the working code: http://s14.postimg.org/ceqdi9mm9/test.png

Comment: Did you check what [`QIODevice::bytesAvailable()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qiodevice.html#bytesAvailable) returns?

Comment: Zero bytes are available

Comment: Also canReadLine() keep returning false.

Comment: Are `m_serialPort` and `m_serial`  the same object?

Comment: Can you try displaying the output with `netcat` instead? If `netcat` fails as well, then the problem is not with your code, it lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the serial port `QIODevice` does not implement `bytesAvailable`, if it returns 0. This may also be why `readAll()` fails, depending on how it is implemented. But at least `readAll()` has the problem of not being able to report error.

Try using `read` method instead for better diagnostics, like this (untested):

```
void DataGathering::newData()
{
    QByteArray rMsg;
    for(;;) {
        char buf[256]; // read data in this size chunks
        qint64 len = m_serial->read(buf, sizeof buf);
        if (len <= 0) {
            if (len < 0) {
                qDebug() << "newData() read error" << m_serial->errorString();
            }
            break; // for(;;)
        }
        rMsg.append(buf, len);
    }
    qDebug() << "newData() got byte array" << rMsg.size() << ":" << rMsg;
}
```

It may not solve your problem, but with luck it will give you error message.